# Javascript: table like data structures as an array of arrays or otherwise?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create a table like data structure in Javascript. The name of the table is 'Positions'. You can think of it as a constant like strucure. One row consists of two items, i.e. '0.2', '0,4'.

As a first draft I wanted to create an array of arrays, but I got some errors that my keyElement I am looking for is not existing. Where is my mistake. Moreover I think maybe there are some other best practices for creating such a data structure.

```
// Positionsarray - Name ist eine Konstante 
var POSITIONS = new Array();
POSITIONS['BG_LEFT_OPEN']    = new Array(0.10, 0.40);       // center 0.25
POSITIONS['BG_RIGHT_OPEN']   = new Array(-0.10, -0.40);     // center - 0.25
POSITIONS['BG_LEFT_CLOSE']   = new Array(0.25, 0.25);   
POSITIONS['BG_RIGHT_CLOSE']  = new Array(-0.25, -0.25);
POSITIONS['BG_CENTER_CLOSE'] = new Array(0.00, 0,00);
//var distance = 0.15;
function jobaOpen(geoArray, constPositionArrayKey){
    console.log("jobaOpen() - constPositionArrayKey : " + constPositionArrayKey);
    var posArray = POSITIONS[constPositionArrayKey];
    var posValueRight = posArray[0];
    var posValueLeft = posArray[1]; 
    ...
```

UPDATE: I tried to use Object Literal Notation - still the same error: var position is not defined.

```
// Positionsarray - Name ist eine Konstante 
var positions = { // Object Literal Notation
        "BG_RIGHT_OPEN" : [-0.10, -0.40],
        "BG_LEFT_OPEN" : [0.10, 0.40],
        "BG_LEFT_CLOSE": [0.25, 0.25],
        "BG_RIGHT_CLOSE" : [-0.25, -0.25],
        "BG_CENTER_CLOSE" : [0.0, 0.0]
};
//var distance = 0.15;
function jobaOpen(geoArray, constPositionArrayKey){ 
    console.log("jobaOpen() - constPositionArrayKey : " + constPositionArrayKey);
    switch(constPositionArrayKey) {
    case "BG_RIGHT_OPEN": // zentral oben geschlossen
        var posArray = positions["BG_RIGHT_OPEN"];
        var posValueRight = posArray[0];
        var posValueLeft = posArray[1];
        break;
    case "BG_LEFT_OPEN": // rechts oben geschlossen
        var posArray = positions["BG_LEFT_OPEN"];
        var posValueRight = posArray[0];
        var posValueLeft = posArray[1];
        break;
    case "BG_LEFT_CLOSE": // Rechts unten geschlossen
        var posArray = positions["BG_LEFT_CLOSE"];
        var posValueRight = posArray[0];
        var posValueLeft = posArray[1];
        break;
    case "BG_RIGHT_CLOSE": // rechts unten offen
        var posArray = positions["BG_RIGHT_CLOSE"];
        var posValueRight = posArray[0];
        var posValueLeft = posArray[1];
        break;
    case "BG_CENTER_CLOSE": // links oben geschlossen
        var posArray = positions.BG_CENTER_CLOSE;
        var posValueRight = posArray[0];
        var posValueLeft = posArray[1];
        break;
    default:
        console.log('default');
    } ...
```

Comment: There is no `keyElement` in the code you posted. Please include the code that is throwing the error, and include the actual error message.

Comment: Arrays are not associative in javascript, stop treating them like they are.

Comment: And what line does this error occur on? I don't see a `position` variable in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have text as array keys (i.e. Associative arrays such as you have in PHP) in JS, only numbers. What you can do though is create POSITIONS as an object and then using the code above, it would create properties for each of the positions and those can be the array.

e.g.

```
// Positionsarray - Name ist eine Konstante 
var POSITIONS = new Object(); // or replace new Object() with {}
POSITIONS['BG_LEFT_OPEN']    = new Array(0.10, 0.40);       // center 0.25
POSITIONS['BG_RIGHT_OPEN']   = new Array(-0.10, -0.40);     // center - 0.25
POSITIONS['BG_LEFT_CLOSE']   = new Array(0.25, 0.25);   
POSITIONS['BG_RIGHT_CLOSE']  = new Array(-0.25, -0.25);
POSITIONS['BG_CENTER_CLOSE'] = new Array(0.00, 0,00);
```

You can then access them by

```
POSITIONS['BG_CENTER_CLOSE']
```

or

```
POSITIONS.BG_CENTER_CLOSE
```